# How to increase the value of a new column after 'N' number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iteration

I have a Dataframe which consists a thousand rows, and I want to add 1 to particular column "Level" after every 100 rows.

I am sharing a small self created sample of how the data looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

data  = {'displayName':['Kelsier', 'Val', 'Elend', 'Dock','Club','Renox','Sher','Breeze','Saze','Reen','Mist','Atium','Iron','Copper','Tin'],
        'pic' : ["av10", "av12", "av14", "av15", "av0", "av1", "av18", "av8", "av16", "av22", "av40", "av24", "av17", "av2", "av7"]}
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

So for example I want the level to be increased by 1 after every 5 rows, and suppose the value needs to start form 6.
As shown below:

I tried loops but I am not very good at it currently

```
import pandas as pd

data  = {'displayName':['Kelsier', 'Val', 'Elend', 'Dock','Club','Renox','Sher','Breeze','Saze','Reen','Mist','Atium','Iron','Copper','Tin'],
        'pic' : ["av10", "av12", "av14", "av15", "av0", "av1", "av18", "av8", "av16", "av22", "av40", "av24", "av17", "av2", "av7"],
        'level':[6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8]}
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

That's all. Thanks for your kind help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) with floor division by 5:

```
df['level'] += np.arange(len(df))//5
```

Or using a default start value:

```
df['level'] = np.arange(len(df))//5 + 6
```

Output:

```
   displayName   pic  level
0      Kelsier  av10      6
1          Val  av12      6
2        Elend  av14      6
3         Dock  av15      6
4         Club   av0      6
5        Renox   av1      7
6         Sher  av18      7
7       Breeze   av8      7
8         Saze  av16      7
9         Reen  av22      7
10        Mist  av40      8
11       Atium  av24      8
12        Iron  av17      8
13      Copper   av2      8
14         Tin   av7      8
```

Comment: What if I don't have a Level column? How will I add the column "Level" and then assign values from suppose 6 onwards while doing the same increment after 5 rows?

Comment: Then use broadcasting: `df['level'] = np.arange(len(df))//5 + 6`

Answer (score 1):

Use integer division by `5` and add to column `level` - solution if default `RangeIndex`:

```
df['level'] += df.index // 5

df['level'] = df.index // 5 + 6
```

Or if not `RangeIndex` is possible create helper array:

```
df['level'] += np.arange(len(df)) // 5

df['level'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 5 + 6
```

Comment: Damn! so simple. Thanks for the quick help,